# Capacitors for 7808 and 7908 regulators

Tags: capacitor, stabilizer

I was looking at datasheets of the 7808 and 7908 regulators from STMicroelectronic.

The mystery for me is why positive voltage regulators have capacitors without polarity (for example ceramic capacitors) and negative voltage regulators have capacitors with polarity (so electrolytic) and also why sizes of these capacitors are different.

---

Schematic for 7808 is:

[image: 7808 application circuit]

---

Schematic for 7908 is:

[image: 7908 application circuit]

---

I also found a schematic for a +-15V power supply in one of these datasheets where capacitors sizes and types are also different:

[image: symetric power supply +-15V]

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Justme says, the 78XX and 79XX series have different internal circuits and therefore have different requirements.

The 79XX requires a higher value capacitor on the input for stability than the 78XX series, and appears to need a low equivalent series resistance (ESR) in the capacitor:

<sub>From the [79XX datasheet.](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l79.pdf)</sub>

[image]

The low ESR is implied by the suggestion to use a tantalum part or an aluminum electrolytic at least ten times larger than the suggested tantalum.  ESR is higher in aluminum electrolytics, and is lower in larger parts.

The reason behind suggesting tantalum or large aluminum electrolytics is that the 79XX (and the 78XX) series parts are **ancient.**  They've been around since the 1970s, and were probably developed in the late 1960s.

Back in those days, a large value capacitor had to be an electrolytic capacitor.  There were no practical large value, physically small capacitors around.  A non-polarized capacitor with a few microfarads capacitance would have been several centimeters long in every dimension.

The 79XX probably doesn't care whether the capacitor is polarized or not.  It just "wants" a capacitor with a large enough capacitance and a low enough ESR.

You could probably use a modern, large value ceramic capacitor just fine if you remember to allow for the effects of the expected input voltage on the ceramic capacitor. (Large value ceramic capacitors lose capacitance when operated near their rated voltage.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

They are different regulators so they have different internal circuitry, requiring different capacitance for stability, and perhaps different capacitor ESR requirements for stability as well. The negative regulator may show polarized capacitors just to emphasize which way to connect them if polarized capacitors are used.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheets generally show the minimum size of capacitor recommended for stability.

Have you ever wondered why there seem to be many more NPN transistors available than PNPs? NPNs are 'better' transistors, in silicon at least. The way the physics works, with the dopants available, they have better parameters, so are cheaper to make for any given specification, or not as good at the same price point.

So although the 7915 is 'just' the inverted polarity version of the 7815, it's been designed down to a similar cost, and that means it's not quite as fast or stable as the 7815, so needs larger capacitors at the terminals to control it.

Comment: The 7915 isn't an inverted 7815. It uses a NPN pass transistor and has a different topology that requires more bypass on input and output.